# Experience Profile interaction visits include notfound.aspx in Sitecore 9 with SXA 1.5

Tags: xdb, sxa, xconnect

My Experience Profile is recording lot of results for page visits to sitecore/service/notfound.aspx

```
Page Events Page not found  /sitecore/service/notfound.aspx 6 min
page view       /sitecore/service/notfound.aspx 6 min
Page Events Page not found  /sitecore/service/notfound.aspx 6 min
```

[image]

I can also see following entries in my IIS logs:

```
2018-02-20 23:59:59 127.0.0.1 GET /sitecore/service/notfound.aspx - 80 default\Anonymous 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/58.0.3029.110+Safari/537.36+Edge/16.16299 http://skylight.local/ 404 0 0 6
2018-02-20 23:59:59 127.0.0.1 GET /-/media/Base-Themes/Core-Libraries/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-ttf.ttf v=4.2.0 80 extranet\Anonymous 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/58.0.3029.110+Safari/537.36+Edge/16.16299 http://skylight.local/ 302 0 0 10
2018-02-20 23:59:59 127.0.0.1 GET /sitecore/service/notfound.aspx - 80 default\Anonymous 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/58.0.3029.110+Safari/537.36+Edge/16.16299 http://skylight.local/ 404 0 0 2
```

I am not sure from where are these requests coming. Does anyone face similar issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried **Google Chrome dev tools**?

I can only imagine what could go wrong.
I reproduced this issue by adding incorrect asset link somewhere. And here you go, I've got **404**.

[image]

`/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx` is just a standard 404 page in Sitecore.

Sitecore redirects to this page if requested address cannot be resolved.

I think you should be able to catch this missing asset or another thing with dev tools.

Sort by status, then search for **404** errors and then read **Initiator** column (in my case `http://sxa_16/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx`)

---

Your IIS log shows that response for `fontawesome-webfont-ttf.ttf` was **302** (redirect), maybe the next request, after redirect is incorrect thus you get **404** as a result.

Comment: yeah it was to do with one of the CSS file missing.